What's the use of the vertical line at 1/3 of the sqlDeveloper worksheet page
i want to ask this question out of curiosity, what's the use of the vertical line in the sql deeveloper worksheet ?
here a screenshot to let you know what i am talking about even if the resolution is bad, but there is a vertical line there
I think might be to help develpers not make long queries but that's not very handy at somepoint,
thanks in advanced.

https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/post/grey-line-in-middle-of-sql-developer-12c-8873#comment_323462168024670228061380628337107053417

There is no line visible in your screenshot (at least not on my screen) because its resolution is too low, but I guess it is a marker for the suggested line length.

It is the visible right-margin and whether it is shown and width of the margin can be set via "Preferences" > "Code Editor" > "Display".
It is used as a guide so that developers (hopefully) do not write excessively long lines of code that will potentially exceed the width of a terminal screen (or other editors) that would then require the line to wrap (or go out of the visible portion of the view).
From thatjeffsmith's Oracle forum post:



Your code will still work if you continue typing past this line. However, people maintaining your code may not like it if your queries have 500 characters on a line and they have to scroll horizontally to read your query (rather than having only 80 characters on a line and scrolling vertically).
